# mysql "Join user ON"

Tags: mysql

i have a sql statement:

```
SELECT user.id, user.nickname 
FROM friends 
LEFT JOIN user ON user.id=friends.desuser where friends.orguser = '".$sessionid."'
```

it works fine and results are like

```
12  user1
33  user3
etc
```

but when in my user DB lets say user1 is deleted, but still there is a record in friends.desuser, I get as result NULL NULL .

What can i do that I minimum would get the UserID like

```
12  NULL
33  user3
```

thank you

Comment: Do a right join instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to return user IDs like that from friends that have been orphaned,

```
SELECT friends.desuser, user.nickname
```

instead of

```
SELECT user.id, user.nickname
```

since the id will not exist in `user` (since there's no matching record in `user`)

Answer (score 0):

either use an `INNER JOIN`. it will only select rows which exist in both tables. or, if you want to still get the ID, but an empty row otherwise, use the `friends.desuser` column. it will be set, because you select from `friends` first (left hand side of the join)